# Google Data Studio: Is it possible to filter results in a Pivot table if less than x records in a cell?

Tags: pivot-table, limit, looker-studio

I am surveying employees (asking them each several "1-5 Opinion Scale" questions) & want to provide relative anonymity by limiting the display of results if there are less than (say) 6 people in the result set.  GDS doesn't allow aggregate filters on pivot tables.  Does anyone know if there is a way around this by using calculated fields or some other mechanism?

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I'd suggest you to add this functionality at the source of your data. For example, if your data is in BigQuery you could import it with a custom query like so:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 `your_table`
WHERE
 5<(
 SELECT
   COUNT(*) AS num_rows
 FROM
   `your_table`)
```

Comment: This example would only work in case your data source is BigQuery. Did you substitute my "your_table" placeholder for your actual table name? If so, where did you add the query and how did it fail?

Comment: Using Postgres dB. And yes to your other question about table name

Comment: Can you tell me what error are you getting? I just tested the same custom query but on a Postgres Data Source and the result is that I get the full table when there are more than 5 entries but not data when there are less.

Comment: I'm not getting an error; its just not limiting the result set.  I'm not sure whether it makes any difference but I SELECTing from a view, rather than a table.